# PHP Schedule Header

Tags: php, html, mysql, xml

So I'm currently writing a website, but have come to a part where I'm not sure how to do it.

On my header I want a schedule. 
This is just a line of text saying what's on next or if it's live.

So currently I have just the HTML,

```
<div class="pull-left header-button">
<a href="#"><strong>Schedule:</strong> Team1 vs Team2 | Tonight at 8:00pm - 9pm</a>
</div>
```

What I want it to do is simple.

When the time is not between 8 - 9pm and this is the next thing on the schedule I want it to display as above.

When the time is between 8 - 9pm I want it to display as

```
<div class="pull-left header-button">
<a href="#"><strong>Live:</strong> Team1 vs Team2 | Now</a>
</div>
```

I prefer that this is done either in MySQL or XML if possible.

I personally have no idea on how to implement this.

Thanks beforehand!

Comment: This is a very broad question.

Comment: What would you want me to explain more. I have no problem in giving more detail :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some kind of programming language to evaluate the time and decide based on the outcome of that evaluation what kind of information to show.

It is not a difficult question, but the answer depends on the supported programming languages on your server (PHP, ASP, .NET, java, python...), and you'll need to learn the basics of the chosen language before jumping head first into it...

Comment: Oh no. I know PHP and HTML. I just don't know how I would code this specific part of the project.